# Как организовать JavaScript код?

Tags: javascript

Как организовать JavaScript код если я пишу не SPA, а только лишь слайдер, валидатор форм и прочие мелочи? И то это всё сторонние плагины которые я не пишу, а просто подключаю.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста суть вопроса. По возможности добавьте ваш код.

Comment: В блоки =) Или самовызывающиеся функции. А там уже или в один файл все это засунуть, или разбить...